# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when including optimizely script

Tags: cors, optimizely

I'm using optimizely in http://www.makeitreal.camp/ but when I open the browser console I'm seeing this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://app.optimizely.com/account/snippet_installed?project_id=3129750879&wxhr=true.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.makeitreal.camp' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It seems that everything is working properly since the diagnose of optimizely says "*Your experiment appears to be implemented correctly.*" but I want to be sure that this error won't affect the experiment.

How can I avoid this error?